# MySQL Выборка пользователей, состоящих ТОЛЬКО в перечисленных группах

Tags: sql, mysqli

Есть таблица tbl_user_groups с полями вида user_id, group_id. Групп много.

Записи вида (пример):
`user_id=2, group_id=3
user_id=4, group_id=8
user_id=2, group_id=7
user_id=8, group_id=3
user_id=6, group_id=8
user_id=1, group_id=4`

Необходимо сделать выборку тех user_id, которые состоят **во всех выбранных** группах из множества, но в других они состоять не должны (которые не из списка).

Что-то вроде `SELECT user_id FROM tbl_user_groups WHERE group_id in (3,4,7,8) GROUP BY user_id // Но нужно ещё, чтобы такой пользователь (user_id) не был (не состоял) участником групп, кроме тех, которые перечислены`

Как это сделать? Спасибо!

Comment: @Bald показывает только тех пользователей, которые состоят только в одной группе. А надо тех, кто состоит в любом количестве групп из списка, но не состоит в других. Если я правильно понял вопрос.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev я понял вопрос немного иначе, на всякий случай думаю стоит попросить тс уточнить этот момент

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev, вы поняли абсолютно верно!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct user_id from tbl_user_groups
where group_id in (3, 4, 7, 8)
and
user_id not in (
    select user_id from tbl_user_groups where group_id in (
        select group_id from groups where group_id not in (3, 4, 7, 8)
    )
);
```

Comment: Супер! Как раз то, что и требовалось. Спасибо вам!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT user_id FROM tbl_user_groups WHERE group_id in (3,4,7,8) GROUP BY user_id
having count(*) = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_id
FROM tbl_user_groups
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING SUM(group_id IN (3, 4, 7, 8)) = 4 
AND SUM(group_id NOT IN (3, 4, 7, 8)) = 0;
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]